# Connecting the emulator to vagrant laravel homestead

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript, nativescript-angular

i have project, its backend uses laravel and I put it to vagrant in virtualbox machine. I have succeeded to access from my local browser. and now I must build android app that calls api from the backend. but it give me error

```
JS: {
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null,
JS:     "headers": {}
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 0,
JS:   "statusText": "Unknown Error",
JS:   "url": "http://izat.test:8000/api/v1/auth/login",
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure response for http://izat.test:8000/api/v1/auth/login: 0 Unknown Error",
JS:   "error": {
JS:     "originalStack": "Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host \"izat.test\": No address associated with hostname\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.fraapp/files/app/vendor.js:91443:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.fraapp/files/app/vendor.js:97223:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\core\http\http-request\http-request.js:43:0)"
JS:   }
JS: }
```

btw I use nativescript-angular for building my android app.
I use API 27 for android emulator

Comment: If `izat.test` is a domain registered in your local machine's config then it may not be available to your Emulator.

Comment: @Manoj Could you tell me how to make it available in my emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have local api path then change it like http://izat.test:8000/api to  http://192.168.10.10:8000/api for local only.

Comment: It still did not work. actually, I use android emulator in windows 10. and then access laravel homestead backend in vagrant. and the izat.test is host in vagrant. I have successfully accessed the api from postman. but not in my emulator

Comment: Try to this Ip address http://192.168.10.10:8000/api. Make sure the IP address listed is the one set in your Homestead.yaml file

Comment: I use just 192.168.10.10, IP that my homestead use. and just the IP. and it works. thanks.
the main problem actually is I declared map to in homestead yaml more than 1. and the api call keep to refer to the other one not my target